# how to prevent the datalabels to overlap

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-2012

I have an ssrs pie chart, as shown below. I have the data lables overlapping. I would like to see the labels such that they do not overlap. Is there a way I can do it ?  I tried increasing the size of the chart in the design mode , reducing the font of the data labels , but dont see any favourable result.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Right-click outside the pie chart but inside the chart borders and select "Chart Area Properties".
- On the 3D Options tab, enable 3D.
- Set "Rotation" and "Inclination" to 0. This will keep the 2D look.

It unfortunately dulls the colors.

Comment: you know why it dulls the colors ?

Comment: no clue, I looked up this problem and paraphrased an answer lol

Comment: Do you have an answer for this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21056447/cannot-see-all-the-labels-on-the-x-asis-in-an-ssrs-column-chart